# No EJB found with interface

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I get this error when the EAR is deployed:

> Caused by:
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:
>   WFLYEJB0406: No EJB found with interface of type
>   'it.ejb32.ConverterBean' for binding
>   it.webtest.SessionBeanTest/converterBean"},

Here's some code:

> Interface

```
package it.ejb32;

public interface Converter {
   float celsiusToFahrenheit(float temperature);
   float fahrenheitToCelsius(float temperature);
}
```

> ConvertBean

```
package it.ejb32;

import javax.ejb.Local;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
@Local
public class ConverterBean implements Converter {

    public ConverterBean() {}

    @Override
    public float celsiusToFahrenheit(float temperature) {
        return temperature * 1.8f + 32;
    }

    @Override
    public float fahrenheitToCelsius(float temperature) {
        return (temperature - 32) / 1.8f;
    }
}
```

> Servlet

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import it.ejb32.ConverterBean;

@WebServlet("/SessionBeanTest")
public class SessionBeanTest extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB
    private ConverterBean converterBean;

    public SessionBeanTest() {}

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Conversion test:"+ converterBean.celsiusToFahrenheit(Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("p"))));
    }

}
```

Do I need to use **@Inject** the interface and not the bean?

Thank you

Comment: Can you annotate the interface as @local or @remote?

Comment: Same..EAR Module ............................... FAILURE [  3.359 s]; I've added @Local at the interface Converter

Comment: The interface needs to be specified on the ConverterBean using this annotation: @Local(Converter.class)

Comment: @Stateless
@Local(Converter.class)
public class ConverterBean implements Converter{

Same, nothing changed

Comment: Is the Interface and Bean in the same ear? Does the Interface and Bean deploy correctly if the SessionBeanTest is omitted?

Comment: Yes..however I've fixed by changing something

Later I'll update the answer thank you

Comment: Change your concrete class to the interface like `private Converter converterBean` that should make things work.

Comment: As you are using local business interface, that is the type you need to inject in servletS not the implementation Bean itself. Yes, you can use Inject annotation instead of EJB annotation.